# Position item outside container in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Take a look: [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/kA2uXVdk17)

I have a sticky navigation header. Its wrapped in `container` however when it becomes sticky it changes the display of the logo image, however I'd like to position it outside of the container, not inside.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Er, just do it? What's the question?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see a logo in your example and I can't scroll to make it sticky.